# Dotnet Core MVC Maintenance Project

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc

After creating some test project on Core MVC 
i find out Kestrel,.. Lock DLL files .

it meant that you can't update your running web site without stopping it.
very disappointing

What should to do ?

Answer (score 1):

This can avoided by a blue green deployment set up - explained  [here](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/blue-green.html) and [here](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html)

Traditionally IIS avoided this by copying the binaries to a temp folder and executed there, it uses some kind of file system watcher to catch up.

Most of the times this should not be a problem as devops approaches and cloud platforms are more and more making it easy to do blue green deployment.